# how I to add array if have a same item on javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example I have data (a,b,c,a,a,c)

I want to make array on javascript like this:

Array(3) :(a,a,a)

Array(1) : (b)

Array(2) : (c,c)

how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a key-value object based on your data.

```
let arr = ['a','b','c','a','a','c'];
const myMap = {};
for (let a of arr) {
    const subArr = myMap[a] || [];
    subArr.push(a);
    myMap[a] = subArr;
}

console.log('myMap', myMap);

const keys = Object.keys(myMap).sort();

for (let key of keys) {
    console.log(key, myMap[key]);
}
```